# How to make a custom method in JpaRepository from Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JpaRepository from Spring Data JPA to call a MySQL db. I know that I don't need to add metods for findById, save, etc becuse they are implemented by Spring, but I want to add a method: `findByAccountNumber()` and I don't know how to do that.

I tried to do in this way but it's not working:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    Account findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber);
}
```

Account class:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name = "accountNumber")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "currentBalance")
    private BigDecimal currentBalance;
}
```

So when I'm calling `accountRepository.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber)` I receive null.

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `accountId` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountNumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `currentBalance` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountId`)
)
```

How can I make this method? Thank you!

Comment: In database, Account exists with searching accountNumber ?

Comment: Yes the column is accountNumber. I updated the post with the table.

Comment: I mean any account data exists in database.where accountNumber is what you are searching for. What is your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks Eklavya, I searched for a data that doesn't exist in the db

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add the [org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/Param.html) annotation.

```
Account findByAccountNumber(@Param("accountNumber") String accountNumber);
```